# How to align several items?

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-align

I've got this code...

```
                <div class="table">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                        <li><a>smth</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

...and this

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

div.table ul li a {
    float: left;
    transition: .2s;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Well, every "smth" is displayed close to each other.

**Output now:**

> smthsmthsmthsmthsmth

**... and they all are floating left.**

**What I need:**

> smth smth smth smth smth

**...floating at the very middle.**

Comment: why not adding some padding or margin? its list not p, and you trying to make list in line

Comment: ...and remove the `float` from the `a`.

Comment: removing float will make everything in separate lines, I added float to align it all in a single line

Comment: make the parent align them centered inside him(using something like flexbox) and add `&nbsp` where you want a space or padding/margin

Comment: can you write the code in answers? @RamondeVries

Comment: use @roko C. Buljan's answer and add this line to the `.table ul ` styling: `justify-content: center;`, and please do your own research for programming. SO is not a free codewriting service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex` and `padding`. Also, use `display: block` on A elements, don't overstyle LI elements, treat them like you would TR or TD elements

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.table ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.table ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <ul>
    <li><a>smth</a></li>
    <li><a>smth</a></li>
    <li><a>smth</a></li>
    <li><a>smth</a></li>
    <li><a>smth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: kind of working, I got the distance between "smth"s, but they still aren't in the middle